ELBO & "backwards" KL divergence argument order
On wikipedia it says: "A simple interpretation of the KL divergence of P from Q [i.e. D_KL(P||Q)] is the expected excess surprise from using Q as a model instead of P when the actual distribution is P"
Yet on the wikipedia page for the ELBO & on the highly cited paper for Bayes-by-backprop it shows the ELBO using the KL "in reverse" (i.e. true distribution is the second argument):

What bothers me even more is that the cost function you actually optimize (below) seems like it would work (better?) even if you didn't use the reversed KL for the prior term... And using KL regularly is just as computationally feasible for that term, although I don't know the theoretical implications as far as derivation of the ELBO goes...

Why does Variational Inference work this way? And what would be the theoretical implications of using ELBO=KL[P(w)||q(w|θ)]+NLL?

"And using KL regularly is just as computationally feasible" this is incorrect; if we were able to take expectations with respect to the true posterior, there would be no need for approximate inference in the first place. Reverse KL is used so ubiquitously because the expectation is with respect to the simple, approximate distribution.

@JohnMadden You misunderstand, when I said it was computationally feasible I was referring to flipping the KL inside the final ELBO cost. The KL that is used to enforce the prior could be KL(P(w)||q(w|θ)) just as easily as KL(q(w|θ)||P(w)) because we have the prior as a closed form Gaussian just like the variational posterior.

@JohnMadden That being said that does answer the first half of the question. Just not the second half.

Does this recent post's answer helps your question, especially its first paragraph? Also a similar relevant recent post discussing theoretical justification of ELBO in VAE.

@profPlum it's probably worth editing the question to make that clear. It's also worth noting that if we use the NLL expected under Q but then the log of densities expected under P, we no longer are using either KL between posterior and approximating distributions, but rather some other cost function. I'm not sure about the theoretical implications of this, and this is in part because of the meta-theoretical implications: KL divergences are (comparatively) easy to analyze theoretically than other cost functions which are not distances between distributions.

A consequence of the fact that our cost function is no longer a divergence between distributions is that we no longer obey the Bayesian updating where putting a datapoint in the prior is the same as putting it in the posterior, as the expectation for these two quantities is now different.

@cinch yes thanks that is very helpful.
